# How to rearrange a list of months in python in the form of calender year

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list in the form of:

```
months = ['August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January']
```

I need the output for the months to be arranged in the form of calendar year as below:

`months : [January, 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']`.

I have been trying to define my custom sort function as shown below:

```
m = {"January":0, "February":1, "March":2, "April":3, "May":4, "June":5, "July":6, "August":7, "September":8, "October":9, "November":10, "December":11}

sorted(months,key=m)
```

But I am getting error as `dict` object is not callable.

I am not sure if this approach is right and how should I proceed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

key takes a function as value that is why you are getting the error. Try this:

```
sorted(months,key=lambda x: m[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
months = ['August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January']

order = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

print(sorted(months,key=order.index))
```

Comment: An explanation, what the posted code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.